# Elastic search wildcard query crashes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I run the query below on a large elastic search cluster. The cluster bcomes unresponsive

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "message": {
              "value": ".*exception.*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "beat.hostname": "ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "lt": 1518459660000,
              "format": "epoch_millis",
              "gte": 1518459600000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I remove the wildcarded `.*exception.*` and replace it with any non wildcarded string like `xyz` it returns fast. Though the query uses a wildcarded expression, it also looks for a small time range and a specific host. I would think this is a very simple query. Any reason why elasticsearch server can't handle this query? The cluster has 10 nodes and 20 TB of data.

Comment: Have you tried with `.*?exception.*`? It should be more efficient (and same what you want).

Comment: Thanks @GáborBakos I will try that. Besides that do you see anything wrong with the query

Comment: ` .*?exception.*? ` does not do any better.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for Regexp Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html). It clearly states the following:

> Note: The performance of a regexp query heavily depends on the regular
>   expression chosen. Matching everything like .* is very slow

What would be ideal is to change the text analysis on the `message` field with a [WordDelimiterTokenFilter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) and set `split_on_case_change` to true. Then something like `NullPointerException` will get indexed as three separate tokens `[Null, Pointer, Exception]`. This can help you search on `exception` without using a regex. Caveat is you need to reindex all your documents.

Another quick thing to try might be to keep your filter conditions on the hostname and timestamp in a [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html), which will prefilter documents before running your regexp query. This may be a short-term solution for you until you fix the text analysis.